# How To Remove Vertical White Space between divs

Tags: html, css

I am having some white space come up between my bordered divs, and I don't want it. Most of the solutions on here delt with divs that had other aspects like width and height, but mine are pure text.

```css
.h1z1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.g1 h2, .g2 h2, .g3 h2 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccffcc; 
}
.g1, .g2, .g3 {
  border-left: 6px solid #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<body style="font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="gtitle">
    <h1 class="h1z1">Graphics Cards</h1>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="g1">
    <h2>Titan XP</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="g2">
    <h2>Titan X (Pascal)</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="g3">
    <h2>GeForce GTX 1080ti</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `margin:0;` to `.g1 h2, .g2 h2, .g3 h2`. because `h2` have default margin.

```css
.h1z1{
  text-align: center;
}

.g1 h2, .g2 h2, .g3 h2{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccffcc;
  margin:0;
}

.g1, .g2, .g3{
  border-left: 6px solid #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<body style="font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="gtitle">
    <h1 class="h1z1">Graphics Cards</h1>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <div class="g1">
    <h2>Titan XP</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="g2">
    <h2>Titan X (Pascal)</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="g3">
    <h2>GeForce GTX 1080ti</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I see the solution was simpler than I thought.

Comment: Please accept as correct answer if answer is helpful for you.

Comment: Will do, Stack makes me wait.